# How does the lithium PHP framework generate a $this context in a PHP page?

Tags: php, frameworks, view, lithium

I've been investigating the [Lithium PHP Framework](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium) and I don't understand how it sets `$this->context;` ([particularly in this layout](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework/blob/master/app/views/layouts/default.html.php).)

Since you cannot simply re-assign `$this` obviously this layout will get included at some point and what confuses me even more is the fact that they use `$this` outside a class definition.

I haven't coded PHP in a while so please help me out here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first idea that strikes me is that this templating page is called from a method.

```
class Viewer
{
    public $html;
    private $title;
    private $content;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->html = new \Utilities\HTMLBag();
    }
    public function loadView($template)
    {
        ob_start();
        include 'path/to/views/'.$template.'.php';
        $this->content = ob_get_clean();
    }
    public function title()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

From this point, the included `$template` can access any method of Viewer's class

Comment: Yup, this is pretty much how Lithium does it. It's also how pretty much almost all PHP frameworks & template libraries using PHP templates do it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply: By calling include/require inside of an method in a class.

File A.php:

```
<?php
class A {
    public $test = 'Hello';

    public function xyz() {
        include 'B.php';
    }
}
```

File B.php:

```
<html>
    <body><?php echo $this->test; ?></body>
</html>
```